# AutoMapper - collection to array returns array with null items

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

My class is like below

```
class MyControl { //..lot of primitive variable
private MyItemCollection items;
public MyItemCollection Items { get { return items; } set { items = value; } }
```

In AutoMapper, I have set it as

```
Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(MyItem), typeof(MyItem));
Mapper.CreateMap<MyControl, MyWebService.MyControl>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Items, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items));
```

In the code, I am providing like this to convert

```
MyWebService.MyControl mc1 = Mapper.Map<MyControl, MyWebService.MyControl>(mc);
```

mc1 contains all primitive data values. But `mc1.Items` contains 3 items with all null. `mc` object has these 3 items populated correctly..

Why the convertion of `MyItem` doesn't happen?

Can someone pls help?

I am trying to convert webservice object to data object.

Comment: I found the reason. MyItem did not have a default constructor.